# What is the meaning of this task?

Tags: trigonometry

Our math teacher gave us some exercises (as she named them) to do in order to prepare ourselves for the upcoming test. Unfortunately I can not understand her what she is asking us to do since her exercises do not include any specific explanation.

So I ask you guys to help me solve this mystery.

Why do we apply trigonometric functions to this task?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Where is the exercise?

Comment: Yeah.  What task are you talking about ?

Comment: The task is the images above. Can you see them?

Comment: In the first picture, she probably wants you to find the angle $\alpha$.

Comment: In the second picture, she probably wants you to find the radius of the circle

Comment: You see the pictures! Good! How am I suppose to find the radius of the circle through an equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula of the linear function looks as $\bbox[lightgreen]{y=kx+b}$.

The parameter **k** has a sense of $\bbox[orange]{the\quad{tangent}\quad {of}\quad{an}\quad{slope}\quad{angle}\quad{of}\quad{a}\quad{line}}$, described by the linear function's equation, to relatively the axis abscissa **x**: $\bbox[lightgreen]{k=\tan(\alpha)}$. Therefore we can calculate the **slope angle relatively axis abscissa** as $\bbox[lightgreen]{\alpha=\arctan(k)}$.

That is why we apply **trigonometric functions** to this task.

From your images we have
$$
y=-3x+2,\implies{k}=\tan(\alpha)=-3,\implies\alpha=\arctan(-3),
$$
$$
y=2x+3,\implies{k}=\tan(\alpha)=2,\implies\alpha=\arctan(2).
$$
As you can see the slope angle of a line, described by the linear function's equation, to relatively the axis **x** depends of the parameter **k**.

Good luck!

Comment: How do I know if the slope (k) has a sense of the tangent of an slope angle? Is this always the case, or is there a situation where the k has a different sense?

Comment: Thank you very much! So I need to take a look at the number 2 of the equation y=2x+3 and there I will find how much is the tangent of the angle. How exactly does the angle helps me solve the whole case? Is there a task where I am provided only with an angle?

Comment: I mean the very case we are discussing. I do not see how much helpful tangent is in the case I presented.

Comment: Let us pretend I understand every bit of what you just said, but without practice I will not be able to understand anything, and that is the main problem with math teachers in Serbia. They do not tend to give us more than two examples. They just write on table formulas and and ask if everything is clear. Students for their part say "yes", but hell it is clear. We need more examples. That is the only way we can understand a theory. So please, give me some similar examples to get familiar with this stuff.

Comment: I am mostly interested in tasks that combine trigonometric and linear functions.

Comment: I understand a bit of Russian, but I am not able to write in Russian.

Comment: Thank you. I am looking for some exercise tasks. That is what I urgently need. That arrogant, hysterical, paranoid mathematician just showed us some basic formulas and examples that she had written on the board before the class had started and she calls that an "explanation".

Comment: Yes. It is helpful. But I must put that piece of advice into practice. :)

Comment: I agree. But where is the magical button to do that?

Comment: Ah, I did not realize that an answer and a comment were two separated things.